# Passing Variables through functions C

Tags: c, function, pointers, chars

Hello im just beginning to learn C and i want to know why im getting a problem here..
i wish to pass a char pointer

```
char *temp;
```

into a function ie call to function

```
checkIfUniqueCourseNo(temp,k);
```

with a prototype

```
int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char checkchar[4],int);
```

and a function header

```
int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char checkchar[4], int k)
```

Im sure im doing something really stupid here but im not sure how to fix it :(
thanks in advance. ps my error is that checkchar[4] outputs a P...

Example---

```
temp = "123A"
checkIfUniqueCourseNo(temp,k);

int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char checkchar[4], int k){
    printf("CheckifUniqueCourse\n");
    printf("Check Value = %c \n", checkchar);

    return 0;
}
```

Output = Check Value = P

Comment: "outputs a P" - what does that mean?  Please clarify what the error is.

Comment: so when i printf checkchar form my checkIfUniqueCourseNo function. it outputs a p. @OliCharlesworth

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen?  "it outputs a p" doesn't give us any clue as to what the problem is.  What's it *supposed* to output?  What does the code actually *do*?  Without this information, we can't be of any help.

Comment: @DanielDC: Please include a complete test-case; it's impossible to tell what's going on with just a few snippets.

Comment: If you do `printf("%c", checkchar[0]);` then you've asked to print only one character. If you do `printf("%s", checkchar);` it might be an error if checkchar is not zero-terminated.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i edited the original question with an example. is that more clear?

Comment: Was `printf("Check Value = %c%c%c%c \n", checkchar[0],checkchar[1],checkchar[2],checkchar[3]);` what you intended ?

Comment: Thanks @Agent_L thats was my problem ! i was outputing it wrong. sorry about the bad question description

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = "123A" 
checkIfUniqueCourseNo(temp,k);  

int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char checkchar[4], int k){
  printf("CheckifUniqueCourse\n");
  printf("Check Value = %c \n", checkchar);
                                ^^^^^^^^^
  return 0; 
}
```

If you're trying to print out the first character of `checkchar`, then you need to change this line to either

```
printf("Check Value = %c\n", *checkchar);
```

or

```
printf("Check Value = %c\n", checkchar[0]);
```

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are equivalent to `T *a`; `a` is declared as a pointer to `T`, not an array of `T`.

When you wrote

```
printf("Check Value = %c\n", checkchar);
```

you lied to `printf`; you said the argument is supposed to be of type `char`, but you passed a `char *`.  Hence the bogus output.

If you want to print out the entire *string* `"1234"`, then you need to change that line to

```
printf("Check value = %s\n", checkchar);
```

This time we use the `%s` conversion specifier to tell `printf` that `checkchar` points to a 0-terminated array of `char` (a.k.a. a string).

Comment: %s is dangerous here. When using char[4] one can not bother with terminating string because length is locked to 4. So once unterminated quad is passed (eg. 4CC), you've got runaway printf.

Comment: @Agent_L: He didn't pass a `char[4]`; he passed a `char *` which in this example points to a 0-terminated string. The `checkchar` parameter *is not a 4-element array*, despite the array notation; it is a pointer to `char`, per 6.7.5.3/7. If he's building non-0-terminated arrays of `char` in his code **and not telling us about it**, then yes, you're correct. But based on his example and description, I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: Yes, he did - in the example, temp var statically assigned. But I suspect the [4] is there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all clear. Are you assigning any value to `temp`? If so, what?

It would make more sense to have your prototype as:

```
int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char* checkchar, int);
```

Since it's not at all clear where you got the 4 from.

Comment: the value i am assigning to temp is a char with 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done C, but I can see a few problems here, `temp = "123A"` actually requires an array for 5 characters (one of which is to include the '\0' string terminating character).

Secondly, the line `printf("Check Value = %c \n", checkchar);` seems to be trying to print a memory pointer as a character, change it to the following: `printf("Check Value = %s \n", checkchar);` and it will output each character in the array until it hits the terminating character.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to look at here, you need to take a good look at the data you have, how it is represented and what you want to do with it.

Your course *code* appears to be a four character string, you should know that traditionally, strings in C also include an extra byte at the end with the value of zero (NUL) so that the many string functions that exist know that they have reached the end of the string.

In your case, your four digit code takes up five bytes of memory. So wont fit well passing it into your function.

If I were you, I would pass in a pointer like so:-

```
int checkIfUniqueCourseNo(char* coursecode, int k ) {
  int rv = -1;
  if ( coursecode == NULL ) return rv;
  //...
```

I have no idea what K is for, do you?

Once you have your sequence of bytes inside your function you can save yourself alot of hastle later by doing some simple bounds checking on the data like so:

```
  //...
  if ( strlen(coursecode) > 4 ){
    fprintf(stderr,"course code too long\n");
    return rv;
  }

  if ( strlen(coursecode) < 4 ){
    fprintf(stderr,"course code too short\n");
    return rv;
  }
  //...
```

You can be sure you have a 4 character string now..